# Как в ELK-стеке отфильтровать логи Nginx по регулярному выражению?

Tags: nginx, логирование, elasticsearch

Здравствуйте, уважаемые. Поднял на днях ELK с целью мониторинга определенных параметров из лога nginx. Настроил Grok, данные идут в нужном формате, в Logstash данные шлет Filebeat. Но не могу понять, в какой из частей стека нужно вбить регулярку, которая будет фильтровать только логи с нужным GET-параметром, т.е. начинающиеся со строки типа /ABC и исключать строки, в которых могут быть данные типа /download/ABC. Сама регулярка простейшая, я это понимаю, но в Кибане я не смог заставить по ней искать данные.

Comment: `url: ^/ABC` не работает?

Comment: Нет. В моем случае это request, но все равно нет